# What is the best open source visual query builder for MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I will need some more flexible alternative to PHP MyAdmin, that could be customized.

Comment: You're planning to customize the program yourself (in what ways?) or why do you want it to be open source? What programming languages are you able to edit in? What operating system(s) are you using and able to compile on (with what tools)? Are you looking for desktop software or a web-based solution?

Comment: This question may be better suited to [dba.se], or possibly [so]. If you'd like it migrated to one of these sites, flag the question for moderator attention and request that it be migrated.

Comment: Thank you. By now I will need something like bookmarked queries on php Myadmin but with more that one parameter, specially with a date picker